# How to replace non-sampled value with previous instance value in time series data file using bash scripting?

Tags: bash, replace, time-series, ascii

I have time series data wherein measurement values from different sensors have been captured asynchronously in same ascii file. The values are white space separated.

Original file looks like below.

```
2022-04-03 21:42:30  10.20      NOTSAMPLED      NOTSAMPLED
2022-04-03 21:45:30  NOTSAMPLED 460     NOTSAMPLED
2022-04-03 21:46:30  NOTSAMPLED NOTSAMPLED      CLOSE
2022-04-03 21:47:30  10.20      NOTSAMPLED      NOTSAMPLED
2022-04-03 21:48:30  NOTSAMPLED 460     NOTSAMPLED
2022-04-03 21:49:30  NOTSAMPLED NOTSAMPLED      CLOSE
2022-04-03 21:50:30  10.19      NOTSAMPLED      NOTSAMPLED
2022-04-03 21:51:30  NOTSAMPLED 460  NOTSAMPLED
2022-04-03 21:52:30  NOTSAMPLED NOTSAMPLED      OPEN
2022-04-03 21:53:30  10.19      NOTSAMPLED      NOTSAMPLED
```

Now barring the non availability of the measurements at a particular time when the other measurement value is available,I need to replace the string "NOTSAMPLED" with the previous instance value of the other sensor like below.

```
2022-04-03 21:42:30  10.20      NOTSAMPLED      NOTSAMPLED
2022-04-03 21:45:30  10.20      460     NOTSAMPLED
2022-04-03 21:46:30  10.20      460     CLOSE
2022-04-03 21:47:30  10.20      460     CLOSE
2022-04-03 21:48:30  10.20      460     CLOSE
2022-04-03 21:49:30  10.20      460     CLOSE
2022-04-03 21:50:30  10.19      460     CLOSE
2022-04-03 21:51:30  10.19      460     CLOSE
2022-04-03 21:52:30  10.19      460     OPEN
2022-04-03 21:53:30  10.19      460     OPEN
```

Can it be achieved using sed/awk or any other bash shell scripting commands ?

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE 2: @**Fravadona** : yours is faster, with a flaw - you forgot to print out the line you took it as part of getline, so it's one-short.

```
f='sample3.txt'; echo; 

 ( time (pvE0 < "${f}" | mawk2 '

       BEGIN { ____["NOTSAMPLED"]
             OFS=sprintf("%c",(___=++_+(++_))^--___)
       } {
           if (NR<___) {
                     NF = split($!_,__)
       } else {    _=NF
               do { __[_]=$_=($_ in ____)? \
                    __[_]:$_ } while(___<--_) } }_' ) | pvE9)  | LC_ALL=C  gwc -lc | ggXy3 | lgp3


     out9:  339MiB 0:00:06 [55.6MiB/s] [55.6MiB/s] [                                 <=>           ]
      in0:  521MiB 0:00:06 [85.4MiB/s] [85.4MiB/s] [=============================>] 100%            
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${f}" | mawk2 ; )  6.03s user 0.27s system 102% cpu 6.131 total
10000000 356000019

j % f='sample3.txt'; echo; 

 ( time (pvE0 < "${f}" | mawk2 '                                             
    
    BEGIN { getline; split($0, filldown) }
    {                            
        for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++)  
            if ($i != "NOTSAMPLED")
                filldown[i] = $i
            else
                $i = filldown[i]                             
    } 1
          '     ) | pvE9)  | LC_ALL=C  gwc -lc | ggXy3 | lgp3

     out9: 5.50MiB 0:00:00 [55.0MiB/s] [55.0MiB/s] [<=>                                            ]
      in0:  521MiB 0:00:05 [96.8MiB/s] [96.8MiB/s] [=============================>] 100%            
     out9:  339MiB 0:00:05 [63.0MiB/s] [63.0MiB/s] [                                        <=>    ]
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${f}" | mawk2 ; )  5.31s user 0.26s system 103% cpu 5.409 total
9999999 355999971
```

**UPDATE 1** :

- benchmarking results using a
  `2.66GB, 60.4mn row` synthetic version of sample data

  ```
   in0: 2.66GiB 0:00:36 [75.0MiB/s] [75.0MiB/s] [===..====>] 100%            
  out9: 2.01GiB 0:00:36 [56.5MiB/s] [56.5MiB/s] [ <=> ]

     60,406,830 lines 2054.705 MB (2154514147) /dev/stdin

  % pvE0 < sample3.txt | mawk2 '

         BEGIN { ____["NOTSAMPLED"]
               OFS=sprintf("%c",(___=++_+(++_))^--___)
         } {
             if (NR<___) {
                       NF = split($!_,__)
         } else {    _=NF
                 do { __[_]=$_=($_ in ____)? \
                      __[_]:$_ } while(___<--_) } }_' | pvE9 | wc4
  ```

Input throughput

- `75.0 MB/s`
- `~1.66 mn rows/sec`

=================================================

```
    < sample2.txt gawk -e '

      BEGIN { ____["NOTSAMPLED"]
              OFS=sprintf("%c",(___=++_+(++_))^--___)
          } {
              if (NR<___) {
                        NF = split($!_,__)
          } else {    _=NF
                  do { __[_]=$_=($_ in ____) ? \
                       __[_]:$_ } while(___<--_) } }_'

2022-04-03  21:42:30    10.20   NOTSAMPLED  NOTSAMPLED
2022-04-03  21:45:30    10.20   460     NOTSAMPLED
2022-04-03  21:46:30    10.20   460     CLOSE
2022-04-03  21:47:30    10.20   460     CLOSE
2022-04-03  21:48:30    10.20   460     CLOSE
2022-04-03  21:49:30    10.20   460     CLOSE
2022-04-03  21:50:30    10.19   460     CLOSE
2022-04-03  21:51:30    10.19   460     CLOSE
2022-04-03  21:52:30    10.19   460     OPEN
2022-04-03  21:53:30    10.19   460     OPEN
```

Tested and confirmed working on `gawk 5.1.1`, `mawk 1.3.4`, `mawk 1.996`, and `macOS nawk`

-- `The 4Chan Teller`

Comment: ++ It takes around 0.5s for 100000 lines; almost two times faster than my solution. But converting my `NR==1` condition to a `getline` in the `BEGIN` block makes mine even faster (0.4s for 100000 lines)

Comment: echo 's=60460830;x=2.66;y=75;z=32^2;w=(z^3 * x)/(z^2 * y);s/w; (100000*w)/s' | bc -l | lgp3

1664768.21…..
0.0600684…..
mine is 0.06007 seconds per 100,000 rows, or 1,664,768 rows/s. using your 0.4s, it's 250,000 rows/s. how is yours faster ?

Comment: I tested it in both Solaris and macOS with a few runs of `time awk '...' /some_ramfs/file_composed_of_10000_times_the_sample_input > /dev/null`. With gawk (Solaris) the codes run faster: in 0.33s for mine and 0.35s for yours

Comment: your sample set is too small - routine OS performance fluctuations alone makes the difference statistically non-meaningful, that's why I benchmarked using a 60 million rows test set, eliminating any advantages from system caching, and measuring purely the throughput rate of the code. ps - any particular reason for not using gawk 5.1.1 instead, or preferably, mawk2 ?

Comment: Well, it's not that I don't want to use gawk5 nor mawk2, it's just that I use the POSIX compliant awk provided by the OS.

Comment: I did a few runs with 10 000 000 records (mine vs yours). Linux (gawk4) 11s vs 11s, macOS 38s vs 49s, Solaris: 80s vs 57s. Different awks, different results...

Comment: see my updated comment above - i found a bug for u

Comment: And if you wanna combine getline, array splitting, performing $1=$1, before printing out the first line, you can do this : print $!(NF=split($(!(getline)),filldown))

Comment: Thanks for finding out the bug that I introduced while optimising the code. I corrected it by adding a `print` after the `split`, IMHO that keeps the code simple to read.

Answer (score 1):

First of.. this is not an efficient answer, but it gets the job done, and shows what is going on.

The file text.txt contains the example input

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x

# first set the variables for the first run
oldfield1="NOTSAMPLED"
oldfield2="NOTSAMPLED"
oldfield3="NOTSAMPLED"
oldfield4="NOTSAMPLED"
oldfield5="NOTSAMPLED"
NOTSAMPLED="NOTSAMPLED"

while read line; do

        field1=$(echo ${line}| cut -d ' ' -f 1)
        field2=$(echo ${line}| cut -d ' ' -f 2)
        field3=$(echo ${line}| cut -d ' ' -f 3)
        field4=$(echo ${line}| cut -d ' ' -f 4)
        field5=$(echo ${line}| cut -d ' ' -f 5)

        [[ ${field1} == ${NOTSAMPLED} ]] && field1=${oldfield1}
        [[ ${field2} == ${NOTSAMPLED} ]] && field2=${oldfield2}
        [[ ${field3} == ${NOTSAMPLED} ]] && field3=${oldfield3}
        [[ ${field4} == ${NOTSAMPLED} ]] && field4=${oldfield4}
        [[ ${field5} == ${NOTSAMPLED} ]] && field5=${oldfield5}

        echo "${field1} ${field2} ${field3} ${field4} ${field5}"

        oldfield1="${field1}"
        oldfield2="${field2}"
        oldfield3="${field3}"
        oldfield4="${field4}"
        oldfield5="${field5}"
done <test.txt
```

Output:

```
2022-04-03 21:42:30 10.20 NOTSAMPLED NOTSAMPLED
2022-04-03 21:45:30 10.20 460 NOTSAMPLED
2022-04-03 21:46:30 10.20 460 CLOSE
2022-04-03 21:47:30 10.20 460 CLOSE
2022-04-03 21:48:30 10.20 460 CLOSE
2022-04-03 21:49:30 10.20 460 CLOSE
2022-04-03 21:50:30 10.19 460 CLOSE
2022-04-03 21:51:30 10.19 460 CLOSE
2022-04-03 21:52:30 10.19 460 OPEN
2022-04-03 21:53:30 10.19 460 OPEN
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution. It is very intuitive. How would be the performance if the number of records are significantly high ? For e,g suppose the file contains 100000 entries ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an `awk` solution that fills down all the `NONSAMPLED` fields (starting from the field #3):

<sub>**edit:** moved `NR==1{split($0, filldown)}` to the `BEGIN` block as it slowed down the processing of big files by two</sub>

```
awk '
    BEGIN { getline; split($0, filldown); print }
    {
        for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++)
            if ($i != "NOTSAMPLED")
                filldown[i] = $i
            else
                $i = filldown[i]
    } 1
' file.txt
```

```
2022-04-03 21:42:30 10.20 NOTSAMPLED NOTSAMPLED
2022-04-03 21:45:30 10.20 460 NOTSAMPLED
2022-04-03 21:46:30 10.20 460 CLOSE
2022-04-03 21:47:30 10.20 460 CLOSE
2022-04-03 21:48:30 10.20 460 CLOSE
2022-04-03 21:49:30 10.20 460 CLOSE
2022-04-03 21:50:30 10.19 460 CLOSE
2022-04-03 21:51:30 10.19 460 CLOSE
2022-04-03 21:52:30 10.19 460 OPEN
2022-04-03 21:53:30 10.19 460 OPEN
```

Here's the `bash` version implementing the same logic. Text processing with bash is slow and isn't considered a good practice, but you might understand it better if you're not familiar with `awk`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
{
    read -ra filldown

    while read -ra fields
    do
        for ((i = 2; i < ${#fields[@]}; i++))
        do
            if [[ ${fields[i]} != NOTSAMPLED ]]
            then
                filldown[i]=${fields[i]}
            else
                fields[i]=${filldown[i]}
            fi
        done
        printf '%s\n' "${fields[*]}"
    done
} < file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the simple solution. How would be the performance, if the number of records are significantly high ? For e.g suppose the file contains 100000 entries ?

Comment: It is fast. `1000 lines: 0.02s`, `10000 lines: 0.1s`, `100000 lines: 0.9s`